# Integral missing in calculating Green's function in momentum space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, greens-functions

so I am reading Zee's qft and I am on the part where amplitudes are calculated for scattering mesons using Wick contraction. At this part the Green's function calculated is given by
$$
-i\lambda\int d^4wD(x_1-w)D(x_2-w)D(w-x_3)D(w-x_4)
$$
Where we can take the Fourier transform to momentum space for $D(x)$:
$$
D(x_a-w)=\int \frac{d^4k_a}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{ik_a(x_a-w)}}{k_a^2-m^2+i\epsilon}
$$
Where $a=1,.,4$. Now plugging into the Green's function equation, the book says it becomes (without $-i\lambda$):
$$
\int d^4we^{-i(k_1+k_2-k_3-k_4)w}={(2\pi)}^4\delta^{(4)}(k_1+k_2-k_3-k_4)
$$
The overall factor for the denominator is included as (but I don't know where the $i$ came from):
$$
\prod_{l=1}^{4}\frac{i}{k_l^2-m^2+i\epsilon}
$$
My questions:

- Where did the integral over k go?
- Where are the factors with $ix_ak_a$ in the exponential?
- Where did the $i$ in the product of the denominator came from?

Comment: Zee is just being really sloppy, if you want more consistent notation you should read another book, like Peskin and Schroeder or [these lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html).

Comment: Ikr? The book I have literally isn't properly edited. But I kinda wanna learn it starting with path integration which seems to be less messy and also learning it as an intro. As of now I'm too deep into this book to read a different one.

Comment: Which pages in Zee?

Comment: from pg 51 (Collision between particles) to pg 54 (Do it once and for all)

Comment: hmm, so no answers still?